How are B-tree and B+tree structures formed?
B+Tree, Data, applied B-Tree, applied B+Tree




I want to know how the B-Tree and B+Tree structures are actually formed? Firstly, do we begin with a non-empty table of data of empty table of data when we index a database table? In the case of a non-empty table its a bit more rational and intuitive. I'm assuming the data is firstly sorted in ascending order, then a random index is generated for each table row, then two table rows are selected e.g n and r with a space between them rows n+1 to r-1. Rows < n, Rows n+1 to r-1 and Rows > r are placed in the 2nd layer nodes. And the splitting repeats for the 3rd layer nodes. This forms the B-Tree. But the B+Tree also requires a duplication of nodes on the final later. I guess a suitable condition would be where the final layer does not complete its references e.g two nodes together should have n+1 or 3 references if only 2 references are completed then it could repeat itself in the layer.
In the case of starting with an empty table, it becomes less intuitive but i would expect the new table row would be randomly index and stored in memory with no reference initally. When a new 2nd data row appears, randomly index it, compare against the 1st data row, store the 2nd data row in memory somewhere and update the 1st data row with a reference to the 2nd data row. The cycle continues, but how is it determined that two nodes are to be stored together? Like for example in the 1st image, node 12 and node 30 are at the top layer stored together. With the algorithm i described you would expect them to be stored separately with a reference from one to the other.
Another assumption, are they even stored together in memory as depicted in the diagram?
You see there's too many implementation details missing from articles i've read.

There are lots of visualizations of this on line, for example this one for B+ trees. The logic for maintaining trees like these is too complicated for most people to just intuit without using pen and paper (or equivalent).

Hey, thats a beast website for animations thanks dude. But yeah im still looking for some text to explain the algorithm of B-Tree and B+Tree formation

Wikipedia has detailed explanations how a b-tree insertion and deletion works. Together with the above web site it should all be clear.
